# Applying filter to a dropdown list - ngoptions

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a method that returns the list of custom types, those values are being used in both the dropdown lists, but now I want to remove a subset of them based on the type and then add to first drop down. I am using angular js, asp.net mvc. What is the best way to apply filter even before data is being rendered and keeping the same method.
Below is the method in the controller which returns names and departments as a json response. Now I want this method to return two different json objects one with subset of the current set being returned based on department they belong to.

```
Public JsonResult GetDetails()
{ 
 List<Cust> Customers = new List<Cust>();
 Customers = GetCustomerDetails();
 var name = Customers.Select(e => new{e.custname}).Distinct().ToList();
 var dept =  Customers.Select(e => new{e.deptname}).Distinct().ToList();
 var response = new{CustomerNames = name, CustomerDepartments = dept};
 return Json(response, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet();
}
```

Comment: Show us some **relevant code** please

Comment: @Shyju Please find the code in the question.

Comment: Please remove the hold, i so need help in fixing this issue.

Comment: I suggest you post a new question with relevant details(code,expected behavior etc).